# XAMPP Wordpress Site is not accessible from production server

Tags: wordpress, ssl, woocommerce, xampp

My Needs are
1. Configure Multiple Domain on XAMPP server on production (Woocommerce Site)
2. Configure and enable ssl

Steps i followed

1. Edited httpd-vshost as

   NameVirtualHost *:80

   ServerAdmin mail@firstsite.in
   DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/firstsite"

       Allow from all

   ServerName firstsite.in
   ServerAlias www.firstsite.in


   ServerAdmin mail@secondsite.in
   DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/secondsite"
   ServerName secindsite.in
   ServerAlias www.secondsite.in

       Allow from all
2. Edited httpd-ssl

   ```
   <VirtualHost _default_:443>
   ServerAdmin admin@localhost
   DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/firstsite"
   ServerName firstsite.in:443
   ServerAlias www.firstsite.in:443
   ErrorLog "logs/example-error.log"
   CustomLog "logs/example-access.log" common
   SSLEngine on
   SSLCACertificateFile "C:\xampp\apache\conf\mibstore\ca_bundle.crt"
   SSLCertificateFile        "C:\xampp\apache\conf\mibstore\server.crt"
   SSLCertificateKeyFile     "C:\xampp\apache\conf\mibstore\server.key"
   </VirtualHost>

   <VirtualHost _default_:443>
   ServerAdmin admin@localhost
   DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/secondsite"
   ServerName secondsite.in:443
   ServerAlias www.secondsite.in:443
   ErrorLog "logs/example-error.log"
   CustomLog "logs/example-access.log" common
   SSLEngine on
   SSLCACertificateFile "C:\xampp\apache\conf\ricebazzar\ca_bundle.crt"
   SSLCertificateFile        "C:\xampp\apache\conf\ricebazzar\server.crt"
   SSLCertificateKeyFile     "C:\xampp\apache\conf\ricebazzar\server.key"
   </VirtualHost>
   ```
3. I have obtained SSL certificate from sslforfree and stored them on relevant path
4. I also edited etc\hosts file

   127.0.0.1 firstsite.in
   127.0.0.1 secondsite.in

Issue

I can able to browse them from the server(windows) itself , but can't able to access them from outside. the relevant domain names are purchased and added a A record to point the IP.

Notes

Using Amazon AWS EC2 instance

```
Added Inbound Rules on 80 & 443, And also added firewall rules on 80 & 443
```

Answer (score 0):

Would you tried in another PC to visit them since you changed your host file on your PC.

If they can be visited then you need remove the record of your host file.

If not, please try:

1. Does both the A record of WWW and Non-WWW have been pointed to IP.
2. If pointed, please tell me what error or message you see on browser when you load the websites.
3. If there're no error or message which means they are blank page, please try to check is there any htaccess file, do you enable the rewrite mod of xampp.